# PHP returns 200 OK status header instead of 404 error over SSL

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have this php script (test.php) which checks whether the page exists in mysql and it should return 404 status header but it returns 200 OK status. This causes soft 404 errors in console.

I tried to fix but it is simply not working. Here is my .htaccess. I migrated my site to SSL few months ago and i am redirecting all traffic to https from port 80.

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/pressrelease([0-9]+)\.htm$ test.php?pressid=$4 [L]
```

and here is my test.php

```
<?php 
include_once('dbc.php');       

$pid = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pressid']));

$rs_dirs = mysql_query("select id,name from categories order by name") or die(mysql_error());

$rs_press = mysql_query("select *
                             from press 
                             where id = '$pid'
                             and approved='1'
                             ") or die(mysql_error());;

$total = mysql_num_rows($rs_press);


if (mysql_num_rows($rs_press) == 0) {

header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
include '404.shtml';
die();
}
```

What is the problem here and how do i fix it?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the actual status code to 404.

See usage of the `header` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

Your code should be:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found", true, 404);
```

There is also an alternative function:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

```
http_response_code(404);
```

I prefer to use the above function instead. As it's more verbose as to what your intention way.

Comment: Sorry, not working. I see a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your code:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($rs_press) == 0) {
   http_response_code(404);
   //and another staff here
}
```

Comment: Not working. I see a blank page.

Comment: Did you include your shtml or echo anything ? Look to the network in browsers. It should show 404 not found

Comment: I checked the code and i am not echoing, but i think the problem has to be with htaccess redirection or headers being leaked somewhere.